# Submit button in loop

Tags: php, submit

I am having a problem using submit button in loop.

What I am trying to do is to show a list from a table in a database and next to each row a submit button.

That insert into a table the id of that row my code is

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($all_rows)-1; $i++) {
<form>
<input type='text' id='name' value='".$all_tv_shows[$i]['id']."' />
<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='addRecord()' />
</form>}
```

I am using AJAX with the submit buttons.
so when i press on any submit button the value that inserted in the table is all the same value (the last row that showed)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What does `addRecord()` do? This must be where your error is. You should probably pass the id as a parameter `addRecord(".$all_tv_shows[$i]['id'].")`

Answer (score 4):

Try this, close the php tags properly

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= count($all_rows)-1; $i++) { ?>
  <form>
      <input type='text' id='name' value='".$all_tv_shows[$i]['id']."' />
      <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='addRecord()' />
  </form>
<php } ?>
```

Comment: Patience, you answered 3 minutes ago. Give the OP at least a few minutes to test the answers we have given him :)

Comment: my code is like yours but i didn't post all the code here
the problem in not a syntex ,
when i press submit it works but only the value inserted in table for all buttons is the same value (the last it showed)

Comment: You just edited your question this is not what your orignally asked :) anyways let me have a look at it#

Comment: on clicking the sumbit button you want to insert data only for the input text associated with that submit button ?

Comment: ok... check the value of each input using your firebug whether each input has the same value or different?

Comment: provide a different id for each submit button and onclick of each submit button take the value of the input associated with that submit button, call ana ajax function and insert that data in the database using ajax... If you dont know how to write all this let me know I will provide some code

Comment: that's exactly what iam trying to do. and it works but only the all the buttons with the same value .

Comment: put your ajax... may be we can find the solution together :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the PHP tags:

```
<?php
    //assuming some other code first...
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_rows); $i++) {
    ?>
        <form>
        <input type='text' id='name' value='<? php echo$all_tv_shows[$i]['id'];?>' />
        <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='addRecord()' />
        </form>
    <?php
    }
```

Also, it's not hugely important, but it might be easier to read if you change the `for` loop as above.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is not in the code you have shown, the problem should be in addRecord javascript function on top of that id is same i.e. 'name' for all element....

You get the value from the form using `$('#name').val();` or `document.getElementById('name');`  and look all input has same id. If I am going right then pass value in addRecord function and use that value.

Comment: i dont get it ... -1 why??... i m still quite sure problem is in javascript and they way he is trying to get data from input field